# python JSON only get keys in first level

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, iterator, key

I have a very long and complicated json object but I only want to get the items/keys in the first level!

Example:

```
{
    "1": "a", 
    "3": "b", 
    "8": {
        "12": "c", 
        "25": "d"
    }
}
```

I want to get **1,3,8** as result!

I found this code:

```
for key, value in data.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

But it prints all keys (also **12 and 25**)

Comment: No, it doesn't. It prints the keys, and the values which themselves include the sub-dictionaries. If you just want to print the keys, don't print the value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: how to print a dictionary's key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904969/python-how-to-print-a-dictionarys-key)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Just do a simple `.keys()`

```
>>> dct = {
...     "1": "a", 
...     "3": "b", 
...     "8": {
...         "12": "c", 
...         "25": "d"
...     }
... }
>>> 
>>> dct.keys()
['1', '8', '3']
>>> for key in dct.keys(): print key
...
1
8
3
>>>
```

If you need a sorted list:

```
keylist = dct.keys() # this is of type `dict_key`, NOT a `list`
keylist.sort()
```

And if you want them as simple list, do this:

```
list(dct_instance.keys())
```

Answer (score 25):

```
for key in data.keys():
    print key
```

Answer (score 11):

As Karthik mentioned, `dct.keys()` will work but it will return all the keys in `dict_keys` type not in `list` type. So if you want all the keys in a list, then `list(dct.keys())` will work.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to check whether a python object is an instance of a type is to use `isinstance()` which is Python's 'built-in' function.
For Python 3.6:

```
dct = {
       "1": "a", 
       "3": "b", 
       "8": {
            "12": "c", 
            "25": "d"
           }
      }

for key in dct.keys():
    if isinstance(dct[key], dict)== False:
       print(key, dct[key])
#shows:
# 1 a
# 3 b
```