# How to read the json file using python in more generic way?

Tags: python, json

I have a json file as follows:

```
    {
    "Alib": {
            "depends": null,
            "locked": false,
            "stage": "xyz",
            "version": "1.2.3"
        }
    "Blib": {
            "depends": null,
            "locked": false,
            "stage": "abc",
            "version": "4.3.8"
        }
    "clib": {
            "depends": null,
            "locked": false,
            "stage": "def",
            "version": "5.2.6"
        }
    }
```

Now i want to read this json file in a way that i get the lib name and the version with respect to that lib. Currently i have solution as follows:

```
    with open (jsonfile) as data_file:
                file = json.load(data_file)
            print file["alib"]["version"]
            print file["blib"]["version"]
            print file["clib"]["version"]
```

I do get the details of the each lib version but this is not exactly what i want.
I dont want to provide the name of the lib hardcoded into the code. It should be something like :

```
  with open (jsonfile) as data_file:
                file = json.load(data_file)
      print file[lib]["version"]
```

and i get the names of the lib along with there versions independently. So, please suggest how shall i acheive this kind of solution where i don't provide the names of the libs and make more generic.

Comment: You json sample is not valid: a comma is missing after each lib attributes.

Comment: You should avoid using `file` as a variable because it is a built-in function (an alias of `open`). For instance, use `json_obj` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Once your json is stored into the variable "file", you can iterate through it to print each element.

```
for lib in file:
    print lib, file[lib]["version"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You json file is loaded as a `dict`. Each key is a library name, values are `dict`:

```
import json
import io

content = '''\
{
    "Alib": {
            "depends": null,
            "locked": false,
            "stage": "xyz",
            "version": "1.2.3"
        },
    "Blib": {
            "depends": null,
            "locked": false,
            "stage": "abc",
            "version": "4.3.8"
        },
    "clib": {
            "depends": null,
            "locked": false,
            "stage": "def",
            "version": "5.2.6"
        }
}'''

fp = io.BytesIO(content)  # can be a real file
json_obj = json.load(fp)
```

You can display the libraries versions like this:

```
for lib, attrs in json_obj.items():
    print(u"{lib}: version={version}".format(lib=lib, version=attrs["version"]))
```

You get:

```
Alib: version=1.2.3
Blib: version=4.3.8
clib: version=5.2.6
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.keys()` function should come in handy.

```
with open (jsonfile) as data_file:
     file = json.load(data_file)
     for key in file.keys():
         print file[key]["version"]
```

See related questions such as [python JSON only get keys in first level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789059/python-json-only-get-keys-in-first-level) for more details.

Comment: Iterating over a dict yields its keys without having to use any method.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about that!