# Get Schema details from the Multiline Json File

Tags: python

The following sample code would read the file as it is but
need spark.read alternative in python to read the schema:

```
import json
with open('F:/Samp_Multiline.json', 'r') as jf:
    weatherData = json.load(jf)
    SS = json.dumps(weatherData)
    SS1 = json.loads(SS)
    print(SS1)
```

Expected output to be schema rather than the actual file contents.

In Spark, this can be achieved by

```
multiline_df.printSchema()
    multiline_df.show(false)
```

but needed the alternative in Python.

Comment: try this print(SS1.keys()) ref:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789059/python-json-only-get-keys-in-first-level

Comment: Thanks for a quick response; Its showing only the first level key but need to schema in whole

Comment: For a Json file, trying to get the schema using python, file is present in windows instead of linux where we can use spark

Comment: {"votes": {"funny": 2, "useful": 5, "cool": 1}, "user_id": "viswa", "name": "viswa", "url": "http://example.org/user_details?userid=viswa", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 12, "type": "user"}

Comment: Schema, I mean the Json  structure for the file