# How do I print the key-value pairs of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to output my key value pairs from a python dictionary as such:

```
key1 \t value1
key2 \t value2
```

I thought I could maybe do it like this:

```
for i in d:
    print d.keys(i), d.values(i)
```

but obviously that's not how it goes as the `keys()` and `values()` don't take an argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: how to print a dictionary's key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904969/python-how-to-print-a-dictionarys-key)

Answer (score 538, accepted):

### Python 2 and Python 3

`i` *is* the key, so you would just need to use it:

```
for i in d:
    print i, d[i]
```

### Python 3

`d.items()` returns the iterator; to get a list, you need to pass the iterator to `list()` yourself.

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```

### Python 2

You can get an iterator that contains both keys and values. `d.items()` returns a list of (key, value) tuples, while `d.iteritems()` returns an iterator that provides the same:

```
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

Answer (score 100):

A little intro to dictionary

```
d={'a':'apple','b':'ball'}
d.keys()  # displays all keys in list
['a','b']
d.values() # displays your values in list
['apple','ball']
d.items() # displays your pair tuple of key and value
[('a','apple'),('b','ball')
```

Print keys,values method one

```
for x in d.keys():
    print(x +" => " + d[x])
```

Another method

```
for key,value in d.items():
    print(key + " => " + value)
```

You can get keys using `iter`

```
>>> list(iter(d))
['a', 'b']
```

You can get value of key of dictionary using `get(key, [value])`:

```
d.get('a')
'apple'
```

If key is not present in dictionary,when default value given, will return value.

```
d.get('c', 'Cat')
'Cat'
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic succinct overview of dictionaries.

Answer (score 38):

Or, for Python 3:

```
for k,v in dict.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 32):

The dictionary:

```
d={'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}
```

Another one line solution:

```
print(*d.items(), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
('key1', 'value1')
('key2', 'value2')
('key3', 'value3')
```

(but, since no one has suggested something like this before, I suspect it is not good practice)

Comment: i think this should definitely be a more accepted answer! ... i feel this answer demos the type of power in python that is mostly ignored... you can also do the follow to get rid of the '()' ... `print(*[f"{': '.join(map(str,v))}" for i,v in enumerate(list(d.items()))], sep='\n')` .... or you can do the following to conveniently print index #'s as well `print(*[f"[{i}] {': '.join(map(str,v))}" for i,v in enumerate(list(d.items()))], sep='\n')`

Comment: Can somebody explain why the * is needed and how it converts dict_values to actual values. Thank you.

Comment: The * operator also works as an "unpacker" (besides multiplying). So what happens is that it unpacks the dictionary items. It doesn't convert, I would say it "opens" the box that d.items() is, and print receives the contents. "unpacking operator python" is the keyword for a more technical explanation.

Comment: not sure why you think this might be not a good practice, while i think a request to access to I/O with `print` command per each key-pair is much worse practice from efficiency point of view

Answer (score 9):

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    print key, '\t', value
```

**For Python 3.x**

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print(f'{key}\t{value}')
```

Comment: I actually tried to use d.iteritems(): first and got AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'. I was using Python 3 and switched ti d.items() and it worked, because iteritems seems to have been removed from Python 3. 

You can read about the difference between Python 2 and 3 in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418481/error-dict-object-has-no-attribute-iteritems

Answer (score 6):

You can access your keys and/or values by calling **items()** on your dictionary.

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: you said ```items()``` in the first line of your text and in the code you put ```iteritems()```. In python3x the correct way is the ```dict.items()``` as you said first.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to **sort** the output by dict key you can use the **collection** package.

```
import collections
for k, v in collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items())).items():
    print(k, v)
```

It works on python 3

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> d={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
>>> for kv in d.items():
...     print kv[0],'\t',kv[1]
... 
a   1
c   3
b   2
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ways already mentioned..  can use 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues'

```
>>> d = {320: 1, 321: 0, 322: 3}
>>> list(d.viewitems())
[(320, 1), (321, 0), (322, 3)]
>>> list(d.viewkeys())
[320, 321, 322]
>>> list(d.viewvalues())
[1, 0, 3]
```

Or

```
>>> list(d.iteritems())
[(320, 1), (321, 0), (322, 3)]
>>> list(d.iterkeys())
[320, 321, 322]
>>> list(d.itervalues())
[1, 0, 3]
```

or using itemgetter

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter(0), dd.items())     ####  for keys
['323', '332']
>>> map(itemgetter(1), dd.items())     ####  for values
['3323', 232]
```

Comment: It appears these methods have been deprecated in later releases of Python 3. 3.10 does not have those methods.

Answer (score 0):

A simple dictionary:

```
x = {'X':"yes", 'Y':"no", 'Z':"ok"}
```

To print a specific (key, value) pair in Python 3 (pair at index 1 in this example):

```
for e in range(len(x)):
    print(([x for x in x.keys()][e], [x for x in x.values()][e]))
```

Output:

```
('X', 'yes')
('Y', 'no')
('Z', 'ok')
```

Here is a one liner solution to print all pairs in a tuple:

```
print(tuple(([x for x in x.keys()][i], [x for x in x.values()][i]) for i in range(len(x))))
```

Output:

```
(('X', 'yes'), ('Y', 'no'), ('Z', 'ok'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To Print key-value pair, for example:

```
players = {
     'lebron': 'lakers',
     'giannis':   'milwakee bucks',
     'durant':  'brooklyn nets',
     'kawhi':   'clippers',    
}
```

for player,club in players.items():

```
print(f"\n{player.title()} is the leader of {club}")
```

The above code, key-value pair:

```
 'lebron': 'lakers', - Lebron is key and lakers is value
```

for loop - specify key, value in dictionary.item():

Now Print (Player Name is the leader of club).

the Output is:

```
#Lebron is the leader of lakers
#Giannis is the leader of milwakee bucks
#Durant is the leader of brooklyn nets
#Kawhi is the leader of clippers
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for pretty-printing a dictionary, check out [Rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich):

```py
from rich import print

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3,
    "strawberry": 1,
    "blueberry": 0.5,
    "mango": 4.5
}

print(prices)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print both key and value, then you can unpack the pair inside the `print()` call.

```py
d={'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}
for x in d.items():
    print(*x)
#         ^  <--- unpack here


key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
```

If you want to print the same output as above using a one-liner, then string concatenation could do the job.

```py
print(*map(' '.join, d.items()), sep='\n')    # option 1
print('\n'.join(map(' '.join, d.items())))    # option 2
```

---

If you want to pretty-print the key-value pairs as a dictionary, then the `json.dumps` in the standard library could be useful to create a string which could be printed.

```py
import json
print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))


{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}
```

Remove the outside brackets and indentation:

```py
print(json.dumps(d, indent=0)[1:-1])


"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
"key3": "value3"
```

Comment: `print(*map(' '.join, d.items()), sep='\n')    # option 1` for one liner does return multiple lines, also if you have integer as key or value it will break.
**Edit:** it does work one line if remove  `, sep='\n'`