# How to unpack key,value pairs in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, object, key-value, keyvaluepair

I'm trying to explore the Algorithmia image taggers in python.

```
client.algo("deeplearning/IllustrationTagger/0.2.5")
client.algo("deeplearning/InceptionNet/1.0.3")
```

But that's not quite relevant to this question, as it applies to dictionaries in general.

```
for dict in dictList:
    print(dict)
```

And this is the output:

> //{'safe': 0.9950032234191896}
>
> //{'questionable': 0.004409242421388626}
>
> //{'explicit': 0.00011681715113809332}

I can access the key just fine:

```
for dict in dictList:
    for key in dict:
        print(key)
```

> //safe
>
> //questionable
>
> //explicit

But when I'm trying to unpack both the key and the value:

```
for dict in dictList:
    for key, value in dict:
        print(key)
        print(value)
```

I get this error:

> for key, value in dict:
>   ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

How can I access both the key and the value ?

EDIT: I've renamed obj and array to dict and list not to confuse with Javascript notation.

Comment: `for key, value in obj.items():`

Comment: Use `for key, value in your_dict.items():`

Comment: I feel so stupid because I remember I've learned that. Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like this - first:

```
for obj in objArray:
    for key in obj:
        value = obj[key]
        print(key)
        print(value)
```

Second (python 3):

```
for obj in objArray:
    for key, value in obj.items():
           print(key)
           print(value)
```

For python 2 you can use `for key, value in d.iteritems()`

Comment: This question has been answered many times, and your answer is the same as always, so it does not bring anything new: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660654/how-do-i-print-the-key-value-pairs-of-a-dictionary-in-python