# Counting characters in a sentence

Tags: python, function, for-loop, count

I'm trying to create a program which outputs how many times a specific character was used.

For example, if the sentence is `I like bikes!`
The output should be:

```
I = 1
l = 1
i = 2
k = 2
e = 2
b = 1
s = 1
! = 1
```

However my program does this

```
I = 1
l = 1
i = 2
k = 1
e = 2
b = 1
i = 2
k = 2
e = 2
s = 1
! = 1
```

So its doubling up the letters.

```
def count_char(text):
    for char in text:
        count = text.count(char)
        print(char + ' = ' + str(count))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `from collections import Counter; Counter(s)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going through all the characters in text, go through all the characters in the alphabet, but report only those that are present:

```
def count_char(text):
    for char in string.ascii_letters:
        count = text.count(char)
        if count:
            print(char + ' = ' + str(count))
```

Comment: I get an error with this though. "string is not defined". What about if I wanted to count characters, instead of just letters. So like numbers and symbols?

Comment: Well, you should import the missing module. It also has collections of digits and other stuff you may want to count.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest initializing a dictionary and  updating the values as you run the for loop

```
def count_char(text):
    answer={}
    for char in text:
        if char in answer:
           answer[char]+=1
        else:
           answer[char]=1
    print(answer)
```

this should give you the desired answer

Comment: How can I print it nicely though, like how I printed it? It prints it in a mess. Like {h: 1, e: 2....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660654/how-do-i-print-the-key-value-pairs-of-a-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If you want your output it ordered, you can derive a class from `OrderedDict` and `Counter`. If order does not matter, you can use `Counter` directly (as suggested by @user3483203 in a comment to your question).

```
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

s = "I like bikes!"

c = OrderedCounter(s)

for char, count in c.items():
    if char.strip(): # skip blanks
        print(char + ' = ' + str(count))
```

Output:

```
I = 1
l = 1
i = 2
k = 2
e = 2
b = 1
s = 1
! = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def char_counter_printer(string):
    if type(string) is not str:
        return False
    else:
        chardict={}
        charlist=[]
        for char in string:
            try:
                chardict[char]+=1
            except:
                chardict[char]=1
                charlist.append(char)

    for ch in charlist:
        if(ch.strip()):
            print(ch,'=',chardict[ch])


char_counter_printer('I Like bikes!')
```

the output is:

```
I = 1
L = 1
i = 2
k = 2
e = 2
b = 1
s = 1
! = 1
```

as expected.