# Extract key-value pairs from text containing brackets (log files)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

Assume this string:

```
[aaa   ] some text here [bbbb3 ] some other text here [cc    ] more text
```

I'd like to and up with a key, value pair like this:

```
Key      Value
aaa      some text here  
bbbb3    some other text here  
cc       more text
```

or a pandas DataFrame like this

```
aaa            | bbbb3                |cc
-------------------------------------------------
some text here | some other text here | more text
next line      | .....                | .....
```

I tried a regex like: `r'\[(.{6})\]\s(.*?)\s\['` but this doesn't work.

Comment: Try `r'\[([^][]*?)\s*]\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\[|$)'`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/EUxFSY/1).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660654/how-do-i-print-the-key-value-pairs-of-a-dictionary-in-python
check this out first.

Comment: Is this to go into a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: @K.Madden: This isn't answering my question. I Need to regex to capture or split my string.

Comment: @coldspeed : not necessarily but I leave that option open

Comment: column name is `aaa`, value is `some text here`, next column is `bbb` and value is `some other text here` etc...

Comment: @PatrickArtner: Sorry typo, updated sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.findall`, and extract regions of interest into columns. You can then strip out spaces as necessary.

Since you mentioned you are open to reading this into a DataFrame, you can leave that job to pandas.

```
import re
matches = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\](.*?)(?=\[|$)', text)

df = (pd.DataFrame(matches, columns=['Key', 'Value'])
        .apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()))
```

```
df
     Key                 Value
0    aaa        some text here
1  bbbb3  some other text here
2     cc             more text
```

Or (Re: edit),

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(matches, columns=['Key', 'Value'])
        .apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
        .set_index('Key')
        .transpose())

Key               aaa                 bbbb3         cc
Value  some text here  some other text here  more text
```

The pattern matches the text inside braces, followed by the text outside upto the next opening brace.

```
\[      # Opening square brace 
(.*?)   # First capture group
\]      # Closing brace
(.*?)   # Second capture group
(?=     # Look-ahead 
   \[   # Next brace,
   |    # Or,
   $    # EOL
)
```

Comment: Many thanks, also for the regex explanation ! Is it possible to use the key as column name ?

Comment: @JohnDoe Re:edit, `pd.DataFrame(matches, columns=['Key', 'Value']).apply(...).set_index('Key').T`

Comment: This is not what I mean. I will try to explain it better. Now the columns are `Key`and `Value` and I would like to see `column=['aaa', 'bbbb3','cc']` from the first captured group and the values from the second captured group. The key value thing is confusing here. I just mentioned here to end up with a dictionary and potentialy end up with a DataFrame

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, figured it out. See my edit showing how to load it in that format. The columns are the keys once you transpose.

Comment: Ok thanks. A bit confusing to me because I still saw the key value as indexes

Comment: This doesn't work if i'm processing multiple lines. Only the last one is added to the DataFrame

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes... because your question had to do with a single string only. Consider opening a new question as a follow up to this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex which captures your key and value in named group captures.

```
\[\s*(?P<key>\w+)+\s*]\s*(?P<value>[^[]*\s*)
```

**Explanation:**

- `\[` --> Since `[` has a special meaning which defines character set, hence it needs to be escaped and it matches a literal `[`
- `\s*` --> Consumes any preceding space before the intended key that doesn't need to part of key
- `(?P<key>\w+)+` --> Forms a `key` named group capturing one or more word [a-zA-Z0-9_] characters. I have used `\w` to keep it simple as the OP's string only contains alphanumeric characters, otherwise one should use `[^]]` character set to capture everything within square bracket as key.
- `\s*` --> Consumes any following space after the intended key capture that doesn't need to part of key
- `]` --> Matches a literal `]` which doesn't need escaping
- `\s*` --> Consumes any preceding space that doesn't need to be part of value
- `(?P<value>[^[]*\s*)` --> Forms a `value` named group capturing any character exception `[` at which point it stops capturing and groups the captured value in named group `value`.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mFWcwW/1)**

Python code,

```
import re
s = '[aaa   ] some text here [bbbb3 ] some other text here [cc    ] more text'

arr = re.findall(r'\[\s*(?P<key>\w+)+\s*]\s*(?P<value>[^[]*\s*)', s)
print(arr)
```

Outputs,

```
[('aaa', 'some text here '), ('bbbb3', 'some other text here '), ('cc', 'more text')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could minimize the regex needed by using `re.split()` and output to a dictionary. For example:

```
import re

text = '[aaa   ] some text here [bbbb3 ] some other text here [cc    ] more text'

# split text on "[" or "]" and slice off the first empty list item
items = re.split(r'[\[\]]', text)[1:]

# loop over consecutive pairs in the list to create a dict
d = {items[i].strip(): items[i+1].strip() for i in range(0, len(items) - 1, 2)}

print(d)
# {'aaa': 'some text here', 'bbbb3': 'some other text here', 'cc': 'more text'}
```

Comment: See the better `str.split()` based approach in the answer from @PatrickArtner (no regex needed).

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not really needed here - simple string split does the job:

```
s = "[aaa   ] some text here [bbbb3 ] some other text here [cc    ] more text"    

parts = s.split("[")  # parts looks like: ['', 
                      #                    'aaa   ] some text here ',
                      #                    'bbbb3 ] some other text here ', 
                      #                    'cc    ] more text'] 
d = {}
# split parts further
for p in parts:
    if p.strip():
        key,value = p.split("]")            # split each part at ] and strip spaces
        d[key.strip()] = value.strip()      # put into dict

# Output:
form = "{:10} {}"
print( form.format("Key","Value"))

for i in d.items():
      print(form.format(*i))
```

Output:

```
Key        Value
cc         more text
aaa        some text here
bbbb3      some other text here
```

Doku for format'ing:

- [custom string formating](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting)
- [string format mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

---

As almost 1-liner:

```
d = {hh[0].strip():hh[1].strip() for hh in (k.split("]") for k in s.split("[") if k)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
import re

s = '[aaa   ] some text here [bbbb3 ] some other text here [cc    ] more text'

pattern = re.compile('\[(\S+?)\s+\]([\s\w]+)')
result = [(match.group(1).strip(), match.group(2).strip()) for match in pattern.finditer(s)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[('aaa', 'some text here'), ('bbbb3', 'some other text here'), ('cc', 'more text')]
```

Comment: @coldspeed Updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

With a RegEx, you can find `key,value` pairs, store them in a dictionary, and print them out:

```
import re

mystr = "[aaa   ] some text here [bbbb3 ] some other text here [cc    ] more text"

a = dict(re.findall(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_\s]+)\]([A-Za-z0-9_\s]+(?=\[|$))", mystr))

for key, value in a.items():
    print key, value

# OUTPUT: 
# aaa     some text here 
# cc      more text
# bbbb3   some other text here
```

The RegEx matches 2 groups:
The first group is *all the characters, numbers and spaces inside enclosed in squared brackets* and the second is *all the characters, numbers and spaces preceded by a closed square bracket and followed by an open square brackets or end of the line*

First group: `\[([A-Za-z0-9_\s]+)\]`
Second group: `([A-Za-z0-9_\s]+(?=\[|$))`

Note that in the second group we have a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?=\[|$)`. Without the positive lookahead, the character would be consumed, and the next group won't find the starting square bracket.

findall returns then a list of tuple: `[(key1,value1), (key2,value2), (key3,value3),...]`.
A list of tuple can be immediately converted into a dictionary: dict(my_tuple_list).

Once you have your dict, you can do what you want with your key/value pairs :)