# Convering json to csv using Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm think what I'm trying to do is very simple. I'm converting .json to a .csv file, but struggling to get exactly what I want. I'm sure I'm being silly, but can't find an answer on this site. Please point out what my silly mistake is!

I'm using the following Python code:

```
import csv, json

inputFile = open('results_20190214b.txt') outputFile = open('results_20190214.csv', 'w', newline='')

data = json.load(inputFile) inputFile.close

output = csv.writer(outputFile)

for row in data:
    output.writerow([row])

outputFile.close()
```

My json looks like this:

```
 {
                "AccumulatedNewCapacity[UTOPIA,E01,1999]": {
                    "Value": 0.0225798659394097
                },
                "AccumulatedNewCapacity[UTOPIA,E01,2000]": {
                    "Value": 0.149302162579271
                },
                "AccumulatedNewCapacity[UTOPIA,E01,2001]": {
                    "Value": 0.354595177554284
                },
                "AccumulatedNewCapacity[UTOPIA,E01,2002]": {
                    "Value": 0.553976916527268
                },
                "AccumulatedNewCapacity[UTOPIA,E01,2003]": {
                    "Value": 0.749394931502283
                }, ETC
```

This code is successfully printing the field names to the CSV, but I am not getting any of the values. E.g:

```
AccumulatedNewCapacity[UTOPIA,E01,1999]
AccumulatedNewCapacity[UTOPIA,E01,2000]
AccumulatedNewCapacity[UTOPIA,E01,2001]
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate the rows as it's also described in here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/26660785/11110555

So, you can do the following

```
for row in data.items():
    output.writerow(row)
```

However, keep in mind you'll be ending up tuples resulting like following on CSV;

```
"AccumulatedNewCapacity[UTOPIA,E01,1999]",{'Value': 0.0225798659394097}
"AccumulatedNewCapacity[UTOPIA,E01,2000]",{'Value': 0.149302162579271}
"AccumulatedNewCapacity[UTOPIA,E01,2001]",{'Value': 0.354595177554284}
"AccumulatedNewCapacity[UTOPIA,E01,2002]",{'Value': 0.553976916527268}
"AccumulatedNewCapacity[UTOPIA,E01,2003]",{'Value': 0.749394931502283}
```

I presume you want to have just part in borders for AccumulatedNewCapacity and Value to CSV

```
for row in data.items():
    # Getting the first part of AccumulatedNewCapacity
    basePart = row[0]
    #Extracting text inside borders
    baseStr = basePart[basePart.find("[")+1:basePart.find("]")]

    # Getting the Value part
    valuePart = row[1]
    #Extracting value
    valueStr = valuePart['Value']

    output.writerow([baseStr,valueStr])
```

This will be leading you to have following result on CSV since it's written as strings but not as list.

```
"UTOPIA,E01,1999",0.0225798659394097
"UTOPIA,E01,2000",0.149302162579271
"UTOPIA,E01,2001",0.354595177554284
"UTOPIA,E01,2002",0.553976916527268
"UTOPIA,E01,2003",0.749394931502283
```

Therefore you need to convert values to list and append value into it.

```
import csv, json

inputFile = open('results.txt')
outputFile = open('results_20190214.csv', 'w', newline='\n')

data = json.load(inputFile)
inputFile.close

output = csv.writer(outputFile)

for row in data.items():
    # Getting the first part of AccumulatedNewCapacity
    basePart = row[0]
    # Extracting text inside borders
    baseStr = basePart[basePart.find("[")+1:basePart.find("]")]

    # Splitting values with comma and turning into list
    writeStr = baseStr.split(",")
    # Getting the Value part
    valuePart = row[1]
    #Extracting value
    valueStr = valuePart['Value']

    # Adding value to the list
    writeStr.append(valueStr)

    # Writing into CSV
    output.writerow(writeStr)

outputFile.close()
```

**Edit:** Forgot to add the result. It'll be resulting like below

```
UTOPIA,E01,1999,0.0225798659394097
UTOPIA,E01,2000,0.149302162579271
UTOPIA,E01,2001,0.354595177554284
UTOPIA,E01,2002,0.553976916527268
UTOPIA,E01,2003,0.749394931502283
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
import csv 
with open('results_20190214b.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('results_20190214.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(( 'title', 'intro')) # here enter your rows titles
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both for your responses - super helpful.

I actually wanted to keep the variable name in the csv as well, so have ended up with a slight variant of Koray B's suggested code:

```
for row in data.items():
    variablePart = row[0]
    variableStr = variablePart[:variablePart.find("[")]
    writeStr = []
    writeStr.append(variableStr)
    variableIndexStr = variablePart[variablePart.find("[")+1:variablePart.find("]")]
    variableIndexStrSplit = variableIndexStr.split(",")
    for i in variableIndexStrSplit:
        indexStr = i
        writeStr.append(indexStr)

    valuePart = row[1]
    valueStr = valuePart['Value']
    writeStr.append(valueStr)

    output.writerow(writeStr)
```