# dict.items() function

Tags: python

```
gender_freq = {}

for row in moma:
    gender = row[5]
    if gender not in gender_freq:
        gender_freq[gender] = 1
    else:
        gender_freq[gender] += 1

for gender, num in gender_freq.items():
    template = "There are {n:,} artworks by {g} artists"
    print(template.format(g=gender, n=num))
```

Why need `.items()` in for loop?
I don't know what is `.items()` function and I can't understand why need it.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: gender_freq is a dict, `items` gives you both keys and values, without `items` it will give only keys.

Comment: if you want to iterate over values you ca use .values()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print the key-value pairs of a dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660654/how-do-i-print-the-key-value-pairs-of-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: I recommend using the Python docs as reference. The [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) section explains `.items` as part of [Looping Techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.items()` returns a list with tuples corresponding to (key, value) pair in the dictionary.

this is your little example:

```
example = {
    'female': 8, 
    'male': 4
}
```

`example.items()` is

```
[('female', 8), ('male', 4)]
```

and when you do:

```
for gender, num in example.items():
```

gender will take these values: `female, male`

and num will take these values: `8, 4`

when using `items()` you are iterating through the items of the dictionary in parallel.

Comment: my pleasure to help.

Comment: It's *not* a list, unless you're still using Python 2.x: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists

Answer (score 1):

`items()` allows you to fetch the key/value pair of the dict in your for loop, this will avoid you looping on keys and asking for the value each time like so:

```
for gender in gender_freq:
    print(template.format(g=gender, n=gender_freq[gender]))
```

One more thing though, use the `defaultdict` this will allow you to avoid the check for the key each time you want to populate your dict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

gender_freq = defaultdict(int)

for row in moma:
    gender = row[5]
    gender_freq[gender] += 1
```