# how to return keys and values from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a dictionary that includes keys as string  and values as list.
My question is how to return the selected keys and values using for loop?

can i save the returned result in a variable in order to print later ?

```
dicts = {"location":["loc1","loc2","loc3"],"category":["cat1","cat2","cat3"]}
```

i tried these lines:

```
keys = sidebars.keys()
values = sidebars.values()
print("keys",keys)
print("values",values)
```

I want to return that the selected key has as values the following items.

```
{key1:[value1,value2],key2:[value1,value2]}
```

Comment: This already has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660654/how-do-i-print-the-key-value-pairs-of-a-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the `item` method of dictionaries.

```py
for key, value in dicts.items():
    print("key = ", key)
    print("value = ", value)
```