# Print dictionary value having a letter '

Tags: python, django

Sorry for the basic question. But I cannot find a solution of this problem.

I'd like to print dictionary value at the Django terminal.

Here, I have a dictionary
c={'code': '12'}

I just want to print 12 at the terminal
But when I enter
print(c.values()) in the terminal,
nothing appears.

I think the latter ' is the problem.
What should I do?

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you explained. Please show us the code you tried so we can reproduce it.

Comment: Printing `c.values()` should output `dict_values(['12'])`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print the key-value pairs of a dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660654/how-do-i-print-the-key-value-pairs-of-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```py
print(c["code"])
```

The `c` variable is a dictionary, `"code"` is a key and `12` is a value.

Comment: If printing `c.values()` didn't give any output then neither will this.