# How do I print out just the values of keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that prints out just the value of the key given in the parameter. But it isn't quite doing what I want it to do. Please have a look at my code and see where I'm wrong? Thanks

```
list = {
    "David": 42,
    "John": 11,
    "Jack": 278
}

def get_marks(student_name):
    for marks in list.items():
        print(marks)

get_marks("David")
```

Comment: Umm, `print(list[student_name])`?

Comment: @Rawing It's a better pratice to use the `get` function of the dict, to prevent you from getting a key error if the element does not exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904969/python-how-to-print-a-dictionarys-key

Comment: @HolyDanna That's an odd statement. What if I want to get a KeyError?

Comment: @Rawing the `get` function allows you to set a default value if no value is found.

Comment: @HolyDanna you should provide a bit more background with a statement like that. `list[student_name]` is often preferred.

Comment: OT, but don't use the variable name `list` for anything, let alone for a dictionary.

Comment: Don't name your list `list`.  This rebinds the list function to your list.  It can make things break

Answer (score 0):

You are trying this:

```
def get_marks(student_name):
    print(list.get(student_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value at a key using  `my_dict[student_name]` but using the `get` method of the dictionary is much safer as it returns `None` when the key is not found:

```
def get_marks(student_name):
    print my_dict.get(student_name)
```

I have renamed your dictionary from `list` to `my_dict` to avoid shadowing the builtin list class.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = {
"David": 42,
"John": 11,
"Jack": 278
}

def get_marks(student_name):
    print list[student_name]

get_marks("David")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the [get()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) method of the dictionary like so:

```
def get_marks(student_name):
    return list.get(student_name)
```

or you can just use [basic dictionary access (Section 5.5)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) and handle missing keys on your own:

```
def get_marks(student_name):
    if student_name in list:
        return list[student_name]
    else:
        #Key not in dict, do something
```