# Print the dict with “key: value” pairs in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to iterate through the dict, `spam`, and print the result in the format of `"key: value"`. There’s something wrong with my code that’s producing a different result.

Is there any ways of correcting the output? And why I’m I getting this output?

```
spam = {'color': 'red', 'age': '42', 'planet of origin': 'mars'}

for k in spam.keys():
    print(str(k) + ': ' + str(spam.values()))
```

The result in getting:

```
color: dict_values(['red', '42', 'mars'])
age: dict_values(['red', '42', 'mars'])
planet of origin: dict_values(['red', '42', 'mars'])
```

The expected result:

```
color: red
age: 42
planet of origin: mars
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a dictionary's key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904969/how-to-print-a-dictionarys-key)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should instead be using `dict.items` instead, since `dict.keys` only iterate through the keys, and then you're printing `dict.values()` which returns all the values of the `dict`.

```
spam = {'color': 'red', 'age': '42','planet of origin': 'mars'}

 for k,v in spam.items():
     print(str(k)+': '  + str(v))
```

Answer (score 4):

`dict.values()` returns a list of all the values in a dictionary. Why not do a key lookup?

```
for k in spam.keys():
     print(str(k)+': '  + spam[k])
```

Or even better:

```
for k, v in spam.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `str(spam.values())` to `spam[k]`. The first option gives all values inside the dictionary, the second one yields the value belonging to the current key `k`.

Comment: No need to cast to a string

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
spam = {'color': 'red', 'age': '42','planet of origin': 'mars'}


for k in spam.keys():

    print(k+  ":"  +spam[k] )
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try?

```
for k in spam:
    print(str(k)+':'+str(spam[k]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below codes,

```
s={'name': 'you', 'number': 123, 'password': '555', 'amt': 800}


for i in s:
    print(i,"=>" ,s[i])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [this article on how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Answers should be properly formatted, in your case, by using code blocks. Also, code is okay, but adding context to it (the reason behind it) is much more useful than the code alone.

Answer (score -1):

do as mathias711 propose you!
In fact what your code do with `str(spam.values())` is to write all the value of the dict.
By doing `str(spam[k])` you get the value associated with the key 'k' in the dict 'spam'.
If you really want your output in a certain order you should have a list with all the keys sorted in this order because by default key of a dictionnary are not ordered.

which that your code look this way:

```
spam = {'color': 'red', 'age': '42','planet of origin': 'mars'} 

liste_ordered_for_output['color', 'age', 'planet of origin']


for key in liste_ordered_for_output:
    print(str(key)+': '  + str(spam[key]))
```