# How to return the key only for a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to print out just only the key from a nested dictionary. For example, I want to print out just only 100 and 111.

```
db = {  100: {"fruit": "orange",
              "dairy": "milk",
              "meat": "steak"},
        111: {"fruit": "apple",
              "dairy": "cheese",
              "meat": "chicken"}
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a dictionary's key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904969/how-to-print-a-dictionarys-key)

Comment: The fact that the values are also dictionaries, is completely irrelevant. You print out the keys of `db` the same way that you print out the keys of any other dictionary, so this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keys()` function to return only keys from a dictionary.

```
print(db.keys())
```

Additionaly, to get values from the dictionary,  `"values()"` function can be used.

```
print(db.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(db.keys())` should do what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate that'll give the keys

```
for k in db:
    print(k)
```