# print key and value of list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I am trying to print the key and value from a list of dictionaries, and I want the output to appear like this.

```
first_name - Michael, last_name - Jordan
first_name - John, last_name - Rosales
first_name - Mark, last_name - Guillen
first_name - KB, last_name - Tonel
```

**this is the code I wrote**

```
students = [
         {'first_name':  'Michael', 'last_name' : 'Jordan'},
         {'first_name' : 'John', 'last_name' : 'Rosales'},
         {'first_name' : 'Mark', 'last_name' : 'Guillen'},
         {'first_name' : 'KB', 'last_name' : 'Tonel'}
    ]
def listd (somelist):
    for key , value in students:
        print(key, '-', value)
print (listd(students))
```

and i get the output with only keys not values

```
first_name - last_name
first_name - last_name
first_name - last_name
first_name - last_name
None
```

what is the mistake I made and how can I view both keys and values?

Comment: You use `.items()` to access (key,value) pairs in dictionaries in python. Beyond that, it's hard to know how to help because your code is not reproducible

Comment: tldr use for ... in, just like with JS<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904969/how-to-print-a-dictionarys-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`students` is a list. You need to iterate over this list to get each dictionary. Then, for each dictionary, you need to iterate over its key-value pairs to format them the way you want using an f-string. Then, you can use `str.join()` to join these values with commas to print what you want.

```
for student in students:
    to_print = []
    for key, value in student.items():
        to_print.append(f"{key} - {value}")

    # Now, to_print is a list that contains two elements:
    # ["first_name - Michael", "last_name - Jordan"]
    print(", ".join(to_print))
```

which gives:

```
first_name - Michael, last_name - Jordan
first_name - John, last_name - Rosales
first_name - Mark, last_name - Guillen
first_name - KB, last_name - Tonel
```

The fancy one-liner:

```
print(*(", ".join(f"{key} - {value}" for key, value in student.items()) for student in students), sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

for sub in students:

```
 for key,values in sub.items():

     Print(key, " : ", value)
```

Just extract each sub dictionary from list and call item method of dictionary on each sub dictionary in loop.unpack the key value tuple and you can play with them as you want..